# Eclipse RCP CommonNavigator Tooltip?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'm trying to add tooltips to our navigator based on the CommonNavigator class with a custom labelprovider. However the tooltips never show up and the implemented methods never get called. I've seen some bugs on the Eclipe Bug Report website but I'm not sure if this is because of the bug or because I'm doing something wrong and if there's a workaround.

These are the main classes (I've changed the classnames).

Navigator View:

```
public class MyNavigatorView extends CommonNavigator {
  //...
  @Override
  public void initListeners(TreeViewer viewer) {
      ColumnViewerToolTipSupport.enableFor(viewer);
      //...
  }
}
```

The Label Provider class:

```
public class MyNavigatorLabelContentProvider extends CellLabelProvider implements ILabelProvider, IStyledLabelProvider {
    //...
    @Override
    public String getToolTipText(Object element) {
        return "Tooltip Test";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean useNativeToolTip(Object object) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Is there a working solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like this: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/167586/

Comment: Thank you Greg, very helpful as always, I'll update my post to post a workaround if others have the same problem. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

For others who have the same problems:

The link greg-449 provided solves this.

I had to override the createCommonViewer method in my view and manually set the label provider:

```
public class MyNavigatorView extends CommonNavigator {
   //...
  @Override
  public void initListeners(TreeViewer viewer) {
      ColumnViewerToolTipSupport.enableFor(viewer);
      //...
  }

  @Override
  protected CommonViewer createCommonViewer(Composite aParent) {
      CommonViewer cv = super.createCommonViewer(aParent);
      cv.setLabelProvider(new MyNavigatorLabelContentProvider());
      return cv;
  }

}
```